# Прошу помощи с микросервисами

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Пишу тестовый микросервис с авторизацией JWT.

```
    package com.zelenko.authservice;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EntityScan({"com.zelenko.entity"})
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.zelenko.Repository")
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(value = JwtConfiguration.class)
    @ComponentScan("com.zelenko")
    @EnableEurekaClient
    public class AuthServiceApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(AuthServiceApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

SecurityCinfig
    package com.zelenko.authservice.SecurityConfig;

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtConfiguration jwtConfiguration;
    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((req,resp,e) -> resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
                .and()
                .addFilter(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(jwtConfiguration.getLoginUrl()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
     public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

filter

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Slf4j
public class JwtUserNameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtConfiguration jwtConfiguration;


    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.info("Attempting Authentification . . .");
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);

        if (applicationUser == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unable to retrieve name or password");

        log.info("Creating user with name {}", applicationUser.getUserName());

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(applicationUser.getUserName(),
                applicationUser.getPassword(), emptyList());
        usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(applicationUser);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("Authentication was successful for the user '{}' generet token ", auth.getName());

        SignedJWT signedJWT = createSignedJWT(auth);
        String encryptToken = encryptToken(signedJWT);
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "XSRF-TOKEN"
                + jwtConfiguration.getHeader().getName());
        response.addHeader(jwtConfiguration.getHeader().getName(), jwtConfiguration.getHeader().getPrefix() + encryptToken);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private SignedJWT createSignedJWT(Authentication auth){
        log.info("Starting to create token");
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = (ApplicationUser) auth.getPrincipal();

        JWTClaimsSet jwtClaimsSet =     createJwtClaimSet(auth, applicationUser);

        KeyPair rsaKeys = genereateKeyPair();

       JWK jwk =  new RSAKey.Builder((RSAPublicKey)rsaKeys.getPublic()).keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build();
       SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.RS256)
               .jwk(jwk)
               .type(JOSEObjectType.JWT)
               .build(), jwtClaimsSet);
       log.info("Signing the token RSA key");

        RSASSASigner signer = new RSASSASigner(rsaKeys.getPrivate());

        signedJWT .sign(signer);

        return signedJWT;
    }

    JWTClaimsSet createJwtClaimSet (Authentication auth, ApplicationUser applicationUser){
        log.info("Create  JWTClaimSet");
        return new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
                .subject(applicationUser.getUserName())
                .claim("authorities", auth.getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(toList()))
                .issuer("zelenko")
                .issueTime(new Date())
                .expirationTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (jwtConfiguration.getDuration() * 1000)))
                        .build();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private KeyPair genereateKeyPair(){
        log.info ("Generate Key");
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(2048);
        return generator.genKeyPair();

    }

    private  String encryptToken (SignedJWT signedJWT) throws JOSEException {
        log.info("Start encrypt token");

        DirectEncrypter directEncrypter = new DirectEncrypter(jwtConfiguration.getSecret().getBytes());

        JWEObject jweObject = new JWEObject(new JWEHeader.Builder(JWEAlgorithm.DIR, EncryptionMethod.A128CBC_HS256)
        .contentType("JWT")
        .build(), new Payload(signedJWT));

        jweObject.encrypt(directEncrypter);
        log.info("Token was encrypt");

        return jweObject.serialize();
    }
}
```

Сущности и репозитории находятся в отдельном модуле core

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="application_users")
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ApplicationUser implements AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;
    @NotNull(message = "The field 'username' is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @NotNull(message = "The field 'password' is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private String password;
    @NotNull(message = "The field 'role' is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
    @Builder.Default
    private String role = "USER";

    public ApplicationUser(@NotNull ApplicationUser applicationUser) {
        this.id = applicationUser.getId();
        this.userName = applicationUser.getUserName();
        this.password = applicationUser.getPassword();
        this.role = applicationUser.getRole();
    }
}
```

Repo

```
package com.zelenko.Repository;


import com.zelenko.entity.ApplicationUser;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ApplicationUserRepository extends JpaRepository <ApplicationUser,Long> {

    public ApplicationUser findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

property

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="jwt.config")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JwtConfiguration {

    private String loginUrl = "/login/**";
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Header header = new Header();
    private int duration = 3600;
    private String secret = "tokensecret";
    private String type = "encrypted";

    public static class Header{
        private String name = "Autorization";
        private String prefix = "Bearer";

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getPrefix() {
            return prefix;
        }

        public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
            this.prefix = prefix;
        }
    }
}
```

Все модули поднимаются без проблем, сервер тоже. Не могу поднять auth.

```
2019-04-06 08:37:29.314  WARN 4932 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'applicationUserRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#158f4cfe' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#158f4cfe': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2019-04-06 08:37:29.314  INFO 4932 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-06 08:37:29.393 ERROR 4932 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field applicationUserRepository in com.zelenko.authservice.user.UserDetailsServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userDetailsServiceImpl)
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

2019-04-06 08:37:29.393 ERROR 4932 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@68567e20] to prepare test instance [com.zelenko.authservice.AuthServiceApplicationTests@6cc86152]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'applicationUserRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#158f4cfe' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#158f4cfe': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Помогите плиз разобраться... Зависимости удалял, по совету Европейских товарищей, не помогло.  Весь код https://github.com/070boroda/microservices

Comment: вообще не понятно что у вас не получается. просто набор символов

Comment: Не компилируется модуль аунтификации

Comment: и что вы хотите от нас?

Comment: `entityManagerFactory` у вас вроде ругается на это, это проблема в сторону базы, смотрите туда

Comment: так же посмотрите на вот эти ответы, возможно вам помогут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318080/unsatisfied-dependency-expressed-through-field-service-no-qualifying-bean-of

Comment: В ошибке указано, что спринг не может найти Бин `entityManagerFactory`. Если Вы его создавали явно, посмотрите, возможно он находиться в другом микросервисе. Если нет, посмотрите, подключен ли модуль `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` в данном микросервисе.

Comment: Еще такой момент (думаю это и так знаете), каждый микросервис - это отдельное приложение. Никакими бинами и прочими настройками микросервисы между собой "не делятся".